Firebase authentication with multiple providers
What's the right way to enable multiple auth providers using Firebase in a Next.js application? Post Sept 15, 2023, Firebase enabled email enumeration protection on all projects. If a user has signed up using email/password, and now tries to sign in using Google, the provider is overridden in Firebase. I have not tried other signup providers. But how do I ensure that users who previously signed up using email/password can sign up using Google and Apple signup while still retaining the password?
What is the behavior when two SAML providers are used? Sign up using Google and log in using Apple.

A user can use multiple auth providers to sign in if you provide a way to link the accounts.  Have you read the documentation about that?

"If a user has signed up using email/password, and now tries to sign-in using Google, the provider is overriden in firebase." That's behavior has been in place since the 2016 relaunch that first support signing in with multiple providers. https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+preferred+provider

@DougStevenson the problem of account linking is that it requires user to be logged in. When more than 2 auth providers are implemented, there's no way to figure out how to tell the user to complete logging in with their initial signup provider before proceeding with the new one. Although the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail exists, it doesn't work if email enumeration protection is enabled.


Post Sept 15, 2023, Firebase enabled email enumeration protection on all projects.

Yes, that's correct. Starting with September 15, 2023, email enumeration protection is enabled by default in all new Firebase projects.

If a user has signed up using email/password, and now tries to sign in using Google, the provider is overridden in Firebase.

This behavior is not related in any way to the email enumeration protection. As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, this is the default mechanism that has worked since 2016. Please check below for more info:

firebase, linkWithCredential to add new auth provider to an Account


Although the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail exists, it doesn't work if email enumeration protection is enabled.

Yes, that is also correct. The email enumeration protection feature improves the security of your Firebase project user authentication accounts, but it disables the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() method, which was previously recommended to be used in identifier-first mechanisms.
Although you can disable email enumeration protection for your Firebase project, I recommend against it because sooner or later you won't be able to do that anymore.

My bad. There is no relation between email enumeration protection and firebase preferred provider. I'll edit the question to make better sense.
But the crux of the question remains. How do I ensure that users who haven't linked google signup to their account to not lose their password information when they login via the google provider? This is not a good UX as we also cannot prompt the user to complete email/password signup before linking google signup, since firebase makes the switch silently. Firebase should allow google signup without account linking if "one account per email" is enabled.

There is no way you can do that. Firebase will automatically override the email and password account in favor of the Google provider. A workaround might be to Implement a mechanism to allow looking up whether the user has already registered outside of Firebase Authentication, for instance, by storing the email addresses in a database of your choice. There is no need to update the question, it's all clear.

Any reason why Firebase chose to implement auth this way? If a user account exists with email/password, Firebase should be able to merge Google signup too right? Why override it? I'm pretty sure a lot of sites allow multiple provider sign-ins without account linkage (I believe Sentry does it). If this is a Firebase specific issue, are there any other auth services that allow this be default? Your help is much appreciated.

If you want to know the reason why the Firebase team implemented a particular mechanism, you should reach out to Firebase Support. Please also keep in mind that, recommendations for software or other services are forbidden, here in StackOverflow.

Good to hear that my help is much appreciated. Can I help you with other information?

Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
